# ffmpeg script encoding only few inputs

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this to create a video from multiple sources. But, the output has only until `frames/300100.PNG`. What should I change to make it encode all my inputs?

```
ffmpeg -i body.mp3 
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 16.368 -i frames/000000.PNG 
    -i 1.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 3.959 -i frames/100100.PNG 
    -i 2.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 6.574 -i frames/200100.PNG 
    -i 3.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 5.134 -i frames/300100.PNG 
    -i 4.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 4.559 -i frames/400100.PNG 
    -i 5.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 5.351 -i frames/500100.PNG 
    -i 6.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 4.390 -i frames/600100.PNG 
    -i 7.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 8.950 -i frames/700100.PNG 
-filter_complex "[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0[v]" 
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to feed all inputs to the concat filter, and set the correct number of inputs in `n`. FFmpeg input index starts from 0. So the fifth input has an index of `4` and would be fed as `[4]` in the concat filter.

```
ffmpeg -i body.mp3 
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 16.368 -i frames/000000.PNG 
    -i 1.mp4
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 3.959 -i frames/100100.PNG 
    -i 2.mp4
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 6.574 -i frames/200100.PNG 
    -i 3.mp4
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 5.134 -i frames/300100.PNG 
    -i 4.mp4
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 4.559 -i frames/400100.PNG 
    -i 5.mp4
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 5.351 -i frames/500100.PNG 
    -i 6.mp4
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 4.390 -i frames/600100.PNG 
    -i 7.mp4
    -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 8.950 -i frames/700100.PNG 
-filter_complex "[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15]concat=n=15:v=1:a=0[v]" 
-map "[v]" -map 0:a -pix_fmt yuv420p out.mp4
```

Comment: You probably contradict yourself: `[1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14][15]` or `[0][1][2][3][4][5][6][7][8][9][10][11][12][13][14]`?

Comment: @MarianD the answer is correct. [0] is not to be fed to the concat filter. See OP's last Q.

Comment: Oh, you're right (as almost always). My inadvertence. :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is *not a new answer* — this is only the *summary of the Gyan's answer:*

- You have 16 inputs (16 times `-i` options) but you enumerated only 7 of them in `[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]` (and declared only 7 of them in `concat=n=7...,`, too):

  > ```
  > -filter_complex "[1][2][3][4][5][6][7]concat=n=7:v=1:a=0[v]"
  > ```

  So you effectively *excluded* the first input `-i body.mp3` with index 0 (which you wanted, because you used it as a background music), but *another 8 with indices 8 to 15, too (which you don't wanted).*

---

The result is that the accepted inputs for the `concat` filter are only from your lines

```
-framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 16.368 -i frames/000000.PNG
-i 1.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 3.959 -i frames/100100.PNG 
-i 2.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 6.574 -i frames/200100.PNG 
-i 3.mp4 -framerate 60 -loop 1 -t 5.134 -i frames/300100.PNG
```

(7 inputs; the first input `-i body.mp3`is omitted.)

It is in concordance with the statement in your question.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Could you also explain what `v=1:a=0[v]` does? I'm trying to add one more `.mp3` as an input. Edit: I'm not looking to overlay the audios.